# Spanning Entire Width of Page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm using Bootstrap to code up a page with a footer. Here is the HTML for the footer:

```
<div class="row">
             <div class="footer1 span12">
                 <span class="offset2">&copy 2013 Me</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is its CSS:

```
.footer1{
    margin-top:520px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    font-size:.5em;
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

Yet for some reason the footer is not spanning the entire width of the page. I have a 12 column nav bar that extends far beyond the width of the footer. The footer looks like it only spans 8 or 10 columns. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: No. Can you post a sample page? Are you using `row-fluid` anywhere?

Comment: Hi userBigNumber, with a link to the actual page, it will be possible to help you with this. Otherwise, there is NO way i can figure out what's happening.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6YBHa/. Are you sure that the navbar and the footer are inside a `<div class="container">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row-fluid` like following and dont put it inside the `container` div or it wont span full-width.

```
<div class="container">
 dont put footer inside it 
 </div>

<div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="footer1 span12">
             <span class="offset2">&copy 2013 Me</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```